# How to compute the fundamental group of $S^2 / A$, where $A$ is a finite set of points?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Along the way to a much simpler solution to a homology problem, I thought about computing the fundamental group of $S^2 / A$. I quickly ran into trouble, so I want to know if there is there a slick way to do this. (For nontrivial |A|, of course.)

I don't think that Van Kampen's theorem works, since the intersection will not be path connected for $|A| \geq 2$. (At least for the obvious covers.)

Comment: What are the «obvious» covers?

Comment: For instance, partitioning the $X = S^2 / {x,y}$ around the reflective symmetry (seen by embedding $X$ into $R^3$ and choosing x and y the north and south poles) and enlarging those partitions to open covers. Then doing similarly for the rest. Or covering the bad point (where they are all glued together) with a contractible neighborhood, and enlarging the complement of that neighborhood to get a covering.

Comment: Van Kampen works, just take neighborhoods of the points. If they're finite then you have a finite cover of S^2 so that intersection of every two neighborhoods is simply connected.
Note that this doesn't work if you have infinite points cause $S^2 - \{p\} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{Q}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is countable and dense (so you can't state that the intersection is simply connected).

Comment: I think this is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $S^2$ with $\left|A\right|-1$ copies of $S^1$.

Comment: @AlessandroFlati I don't think their intersection will even be connected, unless you are choosing your neighborhoods very carefully as in Mariano's answer below.

Comment: @Christoph How do you see that homotopy?

Comment: @Christoph: If you remove $2$ points, it will be hommotopy equivalent to a circle, but not to a sphere wedged with a circle.

Comment: @StefanHamcke We are not removing points, but identifying via a quotient. Sorry, the set minus and set quotient symbols are a little ambiguous.

Comment: Ouch, I didn't read carefully enough, sorry. Well, then @Christoph is right.

Comment: Oh, I can see the homotopy now. Thanks for pointing that out @Christoph.

Comment: Identifying two points is homotopy equivalent to gluing a line segment that connects the points, and that's homtopy equivalent to wedging with a circle, as long as both points are in the same path connected component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do first the following simple computation. Let $D$ be the closed unit disc in the plane and let $A$ be a finite subset of the interior of $D$. What is $\pi_1(D/A)$?

Let $n=|A|$. It does not matter which $n$ points are in $A$, only the cardinal of the set, so we may assume that the points of $A$ are the $n$ vertices of a regular polygon centerd at the origin. Let us take basepoint in $D/A$ to be the (image of) the origin. There is an obvious retract of the space $D/A$ to the space obtaned from a regular $n$-gon by identifing its vertices. This looks like a parachute.

This space can clearly be constructed as a CW-complex as follows: start with one vertex. Next add $n$ $1$-cells in the form of loops, and now glue a $2$-cell in the obvious way. The fundamental group of this space is then $\langle x_1,\dots,x_n:x_1\cdots x_n=1\rangle$. This is easily seen to be a free group in $n-1$ generators.

Now your sphere can be covered with two open sets. One of which is an open disc and the other an open set which deformation retracts to my $D/A$. The intersection is a (thick) circle. Now use van Kampen.

Comment: So the fundamental group is free on $n - 1$ generators, because the loop in the intersection is trivial in the space which deformation retracts to $D / A$?

Comment: Incidentally, I found this much easier to visualize (up to homotopy) by connecting glued points with lines instead of trying to pinch them together.

Answer (score 1):

It seems standard texts fail to take into account the algebraic modelling by the theory of groupoids.

There is a nice construction introduced by Philip Higgins, see his downloadable book [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html), Chapter 8,  in which you start with a groupoid $G$ and a function $f: Ob(G) \to Y$ where $Y$ is any set.  Then there is a groupoid which he writes $U_f(G)$ with object set $Y$ and with a universal property for morphisms $G \to H$ whose function on objects factors through $f$. Thus $U_f(G)$ is obtained from $G$ by "identifying certain objects of $G$", and perhaps adding some.  This construction includes that of free groups, and of free products of groups.

The topological interpretation in terms of the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(Z,C)$ of a space $Z$ for a set $C$ of base points is  given on p.343, 9.1.2 (Corollary 3) of [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html), and was in the 1968 edition of this book.

This answers  the special case of the question, as given by Mariano.

Later: I think also that my and other,  answers to this [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one) on many base points and groupoids are relevant.

Comment: Thanks for these resources - I'll make some time to read them. I have seen the fundamental groupoid developed theoretically, but I don't have any experience doing computations with it. I guess I should develop that.

Comment: You might have a look at arXiv:1404.0556 for a recent use of groupoids. There are not many texts which mention free groupoids on (directed) graphs, an obvious enough idea in this day and age. Good luck!